# Эластичный поиск в mysql ( упрощенная версия)

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Есть хостинг и доступ к базе данных. Хочу сделать `elasticSearch`(упрощенную версию) в момент запроса. Попробовал составить регулярное выражение, но не совсем вышло =(. Идея его такова, что при вводе слова, допускается пару ошибок или отсутствие символа(-ы).  В качестве примера взял слово "Вася" и сделал что-то вроде такого:

```
В?.?.?а.?.?с?.?.?я?
```

или

```
(В..я|..cя|Ва..)
```

Не являюсь гуру в регулярных выражениях, но понимаю, что это не лучший вариант. Регулярное выражение планирую генерировать средствами `PHP`. Может быть кто-то предложит лучший вариант. Спасибо!

Comment: Что значит "но не совсем вышло"? Что вышло?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, в первой регулярке, у меня может искаться все имена, какие содержат 1-6 символов. Со второй лучше... Но думаю может лучше что-то есть

Comment: Может и не лучший, но ведь другого-то способа нет, даже в последних версиях MySQL с поддержкой регулярных выражений ICU нет поддержки fuzzy matching. Поэтому вариант с чередованием может сработать, вот только вместо точек, навреное, лучше подойдёт ``[[:alpha:]]``

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, благодарю, согласен. Но я на тот момент, когда вместо буквы ю, пользователь нажмет "."